# Bootstrap Collapsible Panel not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a collapsible panel, however when pressed, nothing happens.

Here are the CSS files I am using:

```
// Loads all of the CSS styling files needed for view pages to display correctly.
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/jasny-bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/PagedList.css",
          "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
          "~/Content/Site.css"));
```

Here are all of the JS files I am using:

```
// Loads all of the JavaScript files that are needed for view pages to function
// correctly.
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
          "~/Scripts/moment.js",
          "~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
          "~/Scripts/jasny-bootstrap.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js"));
```

These are then rendered using:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Now for my actual code where the collapsable panel is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Item", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse">Collapsible Group</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Everything goes here...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly read the link: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

but the following will help:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseID" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseID">Collapsible Group</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseID" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Everything goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that code, same as before, nothing happens when pressed.

Comment: works here so can post your js that is being used on that page.

Comment: There isn't any JS on the page directly, all of the JS files I have used are referenced in my post. The only small in-line section I have is: $(document).ready(function(){ $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); }); which shouldn't have any impact?

Comment: I guess quickly take your Script.Render out to see if the issue is in there.  Obviously other functionality may be impacted with that being done.

Comment: That's what I also thought was the likely cause and tried it and it appeared to work, just a little buggy. Although, I don't know what would cause the conflict, which is why I came here.

Comment: James, Without knowing all the underlying js files and version of frameworks and libraries its difficult to identify it.  I'd suggest taking a library out at a time from the bundle and see which one is having an impact.  Also check any inter-dependencies, compatibility between versions.  Before all that though check your browser console has not output that could highlight anything.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which version of Bootstrap you're using. By default Visual Studio installs Bootstrap V 2.x.x which i have experienced in many cases does not support accordion/collapse, V 3.x.x does, try updating Nuget package to latest available and you shall be good to go.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am on 3.x.x. I found the issue was with a conflicting JS file.

Answer (score -2):

try use this template
[Bootstrap Accordion example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)
using this tags `data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"`

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but you clearly haven't read my question and just posted me a link to something I've already looked at and then copied and pasted from it.